# Regexp or substr or another method to find a string

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle, substr

I want to reach the best performance and select a "string" only after the word "DL:"

I have a column (varchar2) with values:

```
    DL:1011909825
    Obj:020190004387 DL:8010406429
    Obj:020190004388 DL:8010406428
    DL:190682
    DL:PDL01900940
    Obj:020190004322 DL:611913067
```

so output be like:

```
    1011909825
    8010406429
    8010406428
    190682
    PDL01900940
    611913067
```

I'm not expert in regular expressions, but i tried regexp_replace:

```
regexp_replace(column,'Obj:|DL:','',1, 0, 'i')
```

It's almost OK, but the output is still not the same:

```
    1011909825
    020190004387 8010406429
    020190004388 8010406428
    190682
    PDL01900940
    020190004322 611913067
```

How can i solve this problem & **reach the best performance** ?

Comment: Can `Obj:` follow `DL:`? Do you have `DL:1011909825    Obj:020190004387` like values? The "best" approach depends on how messy your data are and if you need to "pre-validate" your output or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data always looks like this, then `SUBSTR + INSTR` do the job:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (
  3      select 'DL:1011909825' from dual union all
  4      select 'Obj:020190004387 DL:8010406429' from dual union all
  5      select 'Obj:020190004388 DL:8010406428' from dual union all
  6      select 'DL:190682' from dual union all
  7      select 'DL:PDL01900940' from dual union all
  8      select 'Obj:020190004322 DL:611913067' from dual
  9     )
 10  select col, substr(col, instr(col, 'DL:') + 3) result
 11  from test;

COL                            RESULT
------------------------------ ------------------------------
DL:1011909825                  1011909825
Obj:020190004387 DL:8010406429 8010406429
Obj:020190004388 DL:8010406428 8010406428
DL:190682                      190682
DL:PDL01900940                 PDL01900940
Obj:020190004322 DL:611913067  611913067

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

`REGEXP_SUBSTR` might look like this:

```
 <snip>
 10  select col,
 11         ltrim(regexp_substr(col, 'DL:\w+'), 'DL:') resul
 12  from test;

COL                            RESULT
------------------------------ -----------------------------
DL:1011909825                  1011909825
Obj:020190004387 DL:8010406429 8010406429
Obj:020190004388 DL:8010406428 8010406428
DL:190682                      190682
DL:PDL01900940                 PDL01900940
Obj:020190004322 DL:611913067  611913067
```

If there's a lot of data, this should be way faster than regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You may get some idea from this.

```
DL:(.*)

Match 1
1.  1011909825
Match 2
1.  8010406429
Match 3
1.  8010406428
Match 4
1.  190682
Match 5
1.  PDL01900940
Match 6
1.  611913067
```

https://rubular.com/r/jKjcPs8sPr4Ifn

Answer (score 1):

substr + instr will have better performance, but if you want to use regexp:

```
-- substr + instr will have better performance
with s (str) as (
select 'DL:1011909825' from dual union all
select 'Obj:020190004387 DL:8010406429' from dual union all
select 'Obj:020190004388 DL:8010406428' from dual union all
select 'DL:190682' from dual union all
select 'DL:PDL01900940' from dual union all
select 'Obj:020190004322 DL:611913067' from dual)
select str, regexp_substr(str, 'DL:(.*)', 1, 1, null, 1) rs
from s;

STR                            RS                            
------------------------------ ------------------------------
DL:1011909825                  1011909825                    
Obj:020190004387 DL:8010406429 8010406429                    
Obj:020190004388 DL:8010406428 8010406428                    
DL:190682                      190682                        
DL:PDL01900940                 PDL01900940                   
Obj:020190004322 DL:611913067  611913067                     

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: This `DL:(.*)` shows no benefit of using regexps, it does exactly what Littlefoot's non-regex solution does

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively use  <kbd>[`regexp_substr`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_substr.php)</kbd> :

```
with t(str) as
(
 select 'DL:1011909825'                  from dual union all
 select 'Obj:020190004387 DL:8010406429' from dual union all
 select 'Obj:020190004388 DL:8010406428' from dual union all
 select 'DL:190682'                      from dual union all
 select 'DL:PDL01900940'                 from dual union all
 select 'Obj:020190004322 DL:611913067'  from dual 
) 
select regexp_substr(str, '[^DL:]+$') as str
  from t;

STR
----------
1011909825
8010406429
8010406428
190682
01900940
611913067
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/OQQUV73668)</kbd>